# How comes the message I am receving from my php mailer adds random \r\n\r\n to my messages?

Tags: php, html

I have noticed this issue, that when I enter paragraphs in the message being sent from my textarea from the website, I receive the message well but somehow in the paragraphs

> \r\n\r\n

is added in the spaces of the paragraphs. Below is an example of a mail I have received from the form:

> Our Passion leads to design, design leads to performance, performance leads to success. We believe that apps and websites should not only be eye catching but actually provide a great user experience that users will remember.\r\ninfo@world.com\r\n4th Floor, Building\r\nCountry\r\n+222222

When the message I entered is:

*Our Passion leads to design, design leads to performance, performance leads to success. We believe that apps and websites should not only be eye catching but actually provide a great user experience that users will remember.*

*info@world.com*

*4th Floor, Building*
*Country*

*+2222222*

Here is my mail PHP code:

```
 <?php

$name = $_POST['sname'];
$email = $_POST['lemail'];
$message = $_POST['lmessage'];



$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $message);

$to      = 'info@world.com';
$subject = 'Submission from World Contact';


$main = '
<html>
<head>
<title>World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Submission from World Contact</h1>
<h4>New Message in World Contact</h4>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" style="width: 400px; height: auto;">
<tr>
<th style="width: 150px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Stage Name:</th><td> '.$name.'</td>
</tr>
<tr style="width: 150 vertical-align: top; text-align: left; background-color: #e0e0e0;">
<th>Email:</th><td> '.$email.'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 150px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Message:</th><td> '.$message.' </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\n";
$headers .= 'From: Signups' . "\n" .
'Reply-To: info@world.com' . "\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $main, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Ummm.. When you hit `Enter`/`Return` on your keyboard, that is a carriage return / linefeed which is `\r\n`.  You ran this text through something to sanitize etc? To render as HTML use `nl2br()`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Is there a way I could avoid that problem?

Comment: You haven't shown in your code where `$message` comes from, and it looks like that's what contains the content you're asking about.

Comment: @Don'tPanic let me edit it and add that

Comment: @Don'tPanic there! I have added now you can see

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on those values *before* using them in the email. That function is intended to escape values for input into a database. **It is adding the visible `\n` and `\r`.**

From [the documentation for that function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php):

> Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

Try this example:

```
$example = 'something
something else';

var_dump($example);
$example = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $example);
var_dump($example);
```

If you want to preserve the line breaks, use `$message = nl2br($message)` *without* using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, then send the email, then do what you need to do to get the value into your database.

Comment: I also do intend to input the values in a database

Comment: Then escape them after sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

Has suggested by AbaCadaver use `nl2br()`

[PHP nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Pass in your string `$message`

nl2br() changes `\n` and `\r` to `<br/>`

Comment: where you have the `$message` in your html string `$main` just use `nl2br($message)`. Look at the documentation in the link. It shows many easy to read examples. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you submit "new lines" to PHP, they are replaced by `\n` and `\r`. However, when you email it, most email clients read in HTML meaning `\n` and `\r` have no meaning except as text, so they are printed. However, if you want to use new lines, use the PHP function `nl2br()` (New line to br), as follows:

```
$message=nl2br($message);
```

Also, you don't need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as that prepares a string for SQL insertion, not emails.